# how to natively implement a method like [] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, function

So if index_acessor methods like [] and []= weren't hardcoded into the interpreter, is there a way to define such methods directly in Ruby? In other words, how can you define a method name where the param goes inside part of the method name "[*]"

I could've sworn I'd found this at one point either in the Pickaxe or the Ruby Way, but hours of page flipping is leaving me empty handed

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for `Array[]` and `Array[]=`? They are implemented in C. See the source code links in [Array's docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Array) for more information.

Comment: I know they're written in C. However you can also add [] and []= to any custom object, not simply overloading an Array subclass. But I'm thinking I concur that it's just not possible due to the interpreter having them hardcoded and no capability to custom define. (I wonder how Rubinius does it with their whole 'Implement Ruby in Ruby'...)

Comment: This question was really unclear.  You should have given us some example code and said "is this possible?".

Comment: I found what I thought I'd seen, which is the @ in a method name to apply the method name before the object instead of after (e.g. "def -@ " and then you can call "-obj" which works, but that only seems to work for + and - too, though it can be used for any reason for any object.  oh well

Answer (score 5):

```
class Foo
  def []=(k, v)
  end

  def [](k)
  end
end
```

**EDIT1:**

Even though it might not look like it from the definitions, the methods defined above can be called like this:

```
f = Foo.new
f[1] = 2
f[3]
```

Comment: I think the OP wasn't asking specifically about `[]`... they'd like to define, say, `obj<thing>`, and don't know how to get ruby to call such a method.  AFAIK, it's not possibile, since the interpreter just has special rules for the few cases it does handle.

Comment: Correct. so that for example I could write some method definition where it'd end up like object.|val|  despite pipe's not being possible for other reasons, it illustrates the intent

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to define your own methods with funny names, you can only redefine those, whose names are hardcoded into Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Ruby's syntax parser. Normally you could only call a method like `object.method(arg)` but square brackets is a special case (along with a few others). The parser will interpret `object[something]` just as `object.[](something)`, i.e. call method `[]` on `object` with argument `something`.

You can have any method names you like but for fancy ones you will have to use `define_method` instead of `def` and `send` instead of calling the method directly to make syntax parser understand your code.

Here is an example of defining and calling method `<>` on a Greeter.

```
class Greeter
  define_method "<>" do |name|
    puts "Hello, #{name}"
  end
end

Greeter.new.send("<>", "Semyon")
```

Comment: Actually, `[]` and `[]=` can be called as `object.[](1)` and `object.[]=(1,2)`, no need for `send`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce new syntax to Ruby, I think editing parse.y within YARV's source code is the way to go. There's a talk called [parse.y famtour](http://rubykaigi.org/2011/en/schedule/details/18S01) from Rubykaigi 2011 that shows you the kinds of things you can do by editing parse.y.